# Generic method to process multiple List<Class>

Tags: c#, class, generics, propertyinfo

I have multiple `void` methods that basically do the same things:

```
public void SaveToDb1(List<Class1> class1ItemList)
public void SaveToDb2(List<Class2> class2ItemList)
```

etc.... etc...

In each method, I do the same things to each item list.

```
foreach (Class1 item in class1ItemList)
{
    //do work
}
```

Since `Class1 != Class2`, but they perform the same work,how can I make one generic method that handles any class/property combination?

I think I got my answer (thanks!)... But here is the do work portion for clarity.

**EDIT:**

```
//get the type to iterate over their properties
Type _type = typeof(Class1);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//add columns to datatable for each property
foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in _type.GetProperties())
{
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(pInfo.Name, pInfo.PropertyType));
}

foreach (Class1 item in class1ItemList)
{
    DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();

    //copy property to data row
    foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in _type.GetProperties())
    {
        //form the row
        newRow[pInfo.Name] = pInfo.GetValue(item, null);
    }

    //add the row to the datatable
    dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

Comment: What kind of work do the methods do? Also, do `Class1` and `Class2` inherit from some base class?

Comment: @haim770 1st question:  I copy each class/property name and value to a datarow and SqlBulkCopy to a table.  2nd question:  No

Comment: If they perform the same work why use different classes?

Comment: @Magnus how do I define the `void` class though?  `public void SaveToDb1` expects a different List<Class> every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
public void SaveToDB1<T>(List<T> class1ItemList) where T:class
    {
        foreach(T item in class1ItemList)
        {
                    //do something.
        }
    }
```

Invoke method:

```
List<Class1> list=new List<Class1>();
SaveToDB1<Class1>(list);
```

Comment: C# is quite capable to infer the type for this invokation, so there is no actual need to explicitly specify the type of the generic argument.

Answer (score 2):

Have them share an interface

```
public interface IClass
{
 string Name { get; set; }
 string Description { get; set; }
 DateTime Date { get; set; }
 int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your class definitions, you can inherit this class

```
public Class1 : IClass{}
public Class2 : IClass{}
```

Which will allow you to use the interface to determine the type passed in

```
public void SaveToDb1(List<IClass> classItemList)
```

And in that method, you will have access to the IClass exposed properties

```
foreach (IClass item in classItemList)
{
   DateTime date = item.Date;
   string name = item.Name;
   string description = item.Description;
   int quantity = item.Quantity;
}
```

If you are required to have access to Class1 or Class2 then you will need to pass that type in using a generic parameter.

```
public void SaveToDb1<T>(List<IClass> classItemList) where T : IClass, new
```

and then later you could compose your object using that generic type

```
foreach (IClass item in classItemList)
{
   var classItem = new T();
   classItem.Date = item.Date;
   classItem.Name = item.Name;
   classItem.Description = item.Description;
   classItem.Quantity = item.Quantity;
   context.Set<T>.Add(classItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to define a generic method, like below:

```
public void SaveToDb<T>(List<T> classItemList)
```

For more documentation about generic methods, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx).